# Automatic translation of either-sided rotation to fixed directions?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, transmission

Is there a purely mechanical device that takes in clockwise or counter-clockwise rotation 'indiscriminately' and outputs in both cases clockwise rotation?

Comment: Have you done a search and what did you find? What about driving two one-way clutches?

Comment: I didn't know how to look for it, honestly. But I had forgotten the one-ways were a thing, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this, uses two one-way clutches :
[image]

Output is clockwise from the front...

Comment: This is just the thing! I had forgotten one-way clutches were a thing, honestly, but this looks great!